# Automatically added margin - where does it come from?

Tags: html, css

As you can see on the following image, I've created a menu with user navigation icons.

[image: The user menu]

You may have already spotted it, there is a small unwanted margin between the elements.

[image: The user menu with visible margin]

The box itself is produced by the following CSS.

```
background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 30%, 0.30);
border-radius: 5px;
height: 45px;
```

And each individual icon has its own CSS class.

```
.userIcon,
.loginIcon,
.logoutIcon,
.registerIcon,
.settingsIcon
{
    border-right: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
}

.userIcon
{
    background: url(user.svg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 30px;
}

.loginIcon
{
    background: url(login.svg) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 30px;
}

/* ... other icons ... */
```

The box has the following HTML markup.

```
<div class="usermenu">
  <a href="/user" class="userIcon"></a>
  <a href="/settings" class="settingsIcon"></a>
  <a href="/login" class="loginIcon"></a>
</div>
```

I currently have no idea where this margin comes from, nor how I can fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the CSS ending up? In a css file or directly on the element?

Comment: Just so ya know.  One of your classes might not be getting applied because of a syntax error in your markup.  class="userIcon"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your elements are displayed inline block; they are **inline** elements. Inline elements can have spaces between them, which is what the white-space between your elements will become. This space is what you perceive as margin.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzhusLcd/1/)

You can comment out the white-space (or remove it altogether) to overcome this:

```
<div class="usermenu">
    <a href="/user" class="userIcon"></a><!--
 --><a href="/settings" class="settingsIcon"></a><!--
 --><a href="/login" class="loginIcon"></a>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzhusLcd/)

Another way of losing the extra space without having to clutter your markup with comments, is to change the font size to 0 for the parent element, and then set it again for your anchors so it isn't inherited:

```
.usermenu{
    font-size: 0;
}
.userIcon,
.loginIcon,
.logoutIcon,
.registerIcon,
.settingsIcon
{
    border-right: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
    display: inline-block;
    background:#f00;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vzhusLcd/2/)

Comment: The white space will be a regular space, not a non-breaking one

Answer (score 0):

This happens because browsers interpret elements with `display: inline-block` to be "word" type objects that need a space. The two common solutions are:

1. Use `margin-right: -5px` on inline-block elements.
2. Use comments in between inline-block elements:

   `<a href="#">inline-block</a><!--
   --><a href="#">inline-block</a>`
3. Use `float: right` or `float: left` instead of inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options here, but the "margin" is actually whitespace in your HTML. When you set those to `display:inline-block;` you are also causing the browser to think that the actual spaces between the `a` tags are supposed to be spaces.

You can change your HTML to:

```
<div class="usermenu">
  <a href="/user" class="userIcon""></a><a href="/settings" class="settingsIcon"></a><a href="/login" class="loginIcon"></a>
</div>
```

Which will get rid of the margins.

You may also be able to change the following CSS to use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block;`

```
.usericon, .loginicon, .logouticon, .registericon, .settingsicon {
  border-right: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height:45px;
  width: 45px;
}
```

You may need to also implement some type of clearfix on the containing div if you do that, but it's another option if you prefer cleaner code.